# Related to classes and why the code is giving an error

Tags: c++

I want to add two numbers using OOP way. I am a complete newbie in C++ and hence need your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class RunwalsClass{

    public: // public function
        void setName(string x){
            name = x;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        };

    private: // good programming practice to make it private
        string name;

};

class MyClass{

    public:
        void setSaying(string y){
            CoolSaying = y;
        }
        string getSaying(){
            return CoolSaying;
        }

    private:
        string CoolSaying;
};

class FavSitcom{

    public:
        void setSitcom(string z){
            BreakingBad = z;
        }

        string getSitcom(){
            return BreakingBad;
        }

    private:
        string BreakingBad;
};

class AddClass{

    public:
        void setNumbers(int a, int b){
            int answer = a + b;
        }

        int getAddition(){
            return answer;
        }

    private:
        int answer;

};

int main(){

    RunwalsClass RunwalsObject;
    RunwalsObject.setName("Sir Buckey Wallace");
    cout << RunwalsObject.getName() << endl;

    MyClass MyObject;
    MyObject.setSaying("Preaching to the choir! \n");
    cout << MyObject.getSaying();

    FavSitcom MyNewObject;
    MyNewObject.setSitcom("My favorite Sitcom is: Breaking Bad \n");
    cout << MyNewObject.getSitcom();

    AddClass NewObject;
    NewObject.setNumbers("answer: \n");
    cout << AddObject.getAddition();

    return 0;
}


error: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class RunwalsClass{

    public: // public function
        void setName(string x){
            name = x;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        };

    private: // good programming practice to make it private
        string name;

};

class MyClass{

    public:
        void setSaying(string y){
            CoolSaying = y;
        }
        string getSaying(){
            return CoolSaying;
        }

    private:
        string CoolSaying;
};

class FavSitcom{

    public:
        void setSitcom(string z){
            BreakingBad = z;
        }

        string getSitcom(){
            return BreakingBad;
        }

    private:
        string BreakingBad;
};

class AddClass{

    public:
        void setNumbers(int a, int b){
            int answer = a + b;
        }

        int getAddition(){
            return answer;
        }

    private:
        int answer;

};

int main(){

    RunwalsClass RunwalsObject;
    RunwalsObject.setName("Sir Buckey Wallace");
    cout << RunwalsObject.getName() << endl;

    MyClass MyObject;
    MyObject.setSaying("Preaching to the choir! \n");
    cout << MyObject.getSaying();

    FavSitcom MyNewObject;
    MyNewObject.setSitcom("My favorite Sitcom is: Breaking Bad \n");
    cout << MyNewObject.getSitcom();

    AddClass NewObject;
    NewObject.setNumbers("answer: \n");
    cout << AddObject.getAddition();

    return 0;
}
```

Reported error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'AddClass::setNumbers(const char [10])
note: candidate: void AddClass::setNumbers(int, int)
note: candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided.
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Isn't that error clear enough? You declared a member function in `AddClass` which expects **two** arguments. You called this member function with `NewObject.setNumbers("answer: \n");` - that's **one** argument. (The compiler didn't complain explicitly that the type of argument isn't matching but it will as soon as you provide the correct number of arguments.)

Comment: Also this is wrong: `void setNumbers(int a, int b){int answer = a + b;}` as it declares and sets a new _local_ called `answer` instead of the relevant member.

Comment: The beauty of the MCVE is it reduces the code to the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. When your program gets down to the few lines required to reproduce a bug, it's usually easy to see and be able to fix the error.

Comment: May be, it was confusing to you that it didn't say: That doesn't match! but something with "candidates". That's because there could be multiple functions with same name where the number and types of arguments is used to choose the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main, your are passing a string as parameter to your setNumbers method. This line is wrong in main:

```
     NewObject.setNumbers("answer: \n");
```

Your setNumbers function neeeds 2 integers as it is declared. Try:

```
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;
    NewObject.setNumbers(a, b);
```

Good luck in your OOP learning journey!

**EDIT**: 
Also, in your setNumbers function, you must not redeclare answer because this variable is a class member. Remove int, just use answer inside setNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yep so your function setNumbers() expects two integer arguments provided, i.e. NewObject.setNumbers(5, 10); which would set the number to 15. You have provided a string literal "answer: \n" which is not the same and therefore will not compile.